# How to compute the derivative of a cubic spline interpolation using scipy?

Tags: scipy

I have dataset which look like this :

```
position number_of_tag_at_this_position
3 4
8 6
13 25
23 12
```

I want to apply cubic spline interpolation to this dataset to interpolate tag density; to do so, i run :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate`
x = [3,8,13,23]`
y = [4,6,25,12]`
tck = interpolate.splrep(x,y) # cubic`
```

And now, i would like to calculate the derivative of the function at each point of the interpolation, How can i do this ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

See the manual:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html

Note parameter `der`.